# PHP Define variable with foreach from array

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling

Here's my code

```
<?php

$serverArray = []; 
$con=mysqli_connect("--","--","--","--");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="SELECT ipaddress FROM gmodservers";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    array_push($serverArray,$row);
    print_r($serverArray);
}


// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);

///ServerPull///

require __DIR__ . '/../SourceQuery/bootstrap.php';

use xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery;

// For the sake of this example
Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );
// Edit this ->
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', 27015 );
define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery::SOURCE );
foreach ($serverArray as $value) {
define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $value );
// Edit this <-

$Query = new SourceQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetRules( ) );
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
}

$Query->Disconnect( );
```

I have IP's in an SQL database. I move the IP's to an array. I then want to use the function at the bottom to print all the information about all IP addresses from the array. However, I get this error:

> Could not create socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
>   **Notice**:  Constant SQ_SERVER_ADDR already defined in **G:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP-Source-Query-master\Examples\list.php** on line **40**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `constant` It can not be re-declare, so for server address use variable. change your `foreach` loop as below

```
foreach ($serverArray as $value) {
//define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $value );
$server_address = $value;
// Edit this <-

$Query = new SourceQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( $server_address, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );
    print_r( $Query->GetRules( ) );
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
}
```

**EDIT**

In while loop of data base result you are adding entire row to array you need to add `ipaddress` only

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    array_push($serverArray,$row['ipaddress']);
    print_r($serverArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I got this error: Could not create socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: Check your host is valid or not

Comment: The address in the array is valid. It worked when I did define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', '208.103.169.12' ); However, then it only worked with one and was hardcoded ofc.